# C++ How to _wfindfirst and _wfindclose on Win64 Win32

Tags: c++, wchar-t, findfirst

I have a piece of code to run on Windows that uses char const for a filename:

```
 char const * filename
 _finddata_t fi;
 intptr_t n;
 if ((n = _findfirst(filename, &fi)) != -1) {
   _findclose(n);
   return TRUE;
 }
```

Now I want this to use this code using const wchar_t for a filename (it should still run on Windows). I would assume this would be the way to do (see below). But in the description of _wfindclose it says _wfindclose is only usable for Win NT. Since one should use _wfindclose() to close the handle: **How do I close the handle in Win64? **

```
 wchar_t const * filename
 _wfinddata_t fi;
 intptr_t n;
 if ((n = _wfindfirst(filename, &fi)) != -1) {
   _wfindclose(n);
   return TRUE;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: `_findclose` requires only an argument of type `intptr_t`. Nothing related to text formats, so you should be able to use it (no need for a `'w'` "flavor").

Comment: Another option would be to use [std::filesystem::directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a library. No matter.

If you `#include <windows.h>` you can drop it.

`_finddata_t` is `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`
`_wfinddata_t`  is `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`
`_findfirst` is `FindFirstFileA`
`_wfindfirst` is `FindFirstFileW`
`???` is `FindNextFileA`
`???` is `FindNextFileW`
`_findclose` is `FindClose`
`_wfindclose` is `FindClose`

With a library as silly as this one I recommend dropping it. A better abstraction can finally be written if you really case.